# NameError: undefined local variable or method in rspec for rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

There is a method assign_user_rights which is defined in application controller in rails 3.2.8 app. In applications_controller_spec.rb, there is a test case for the method:

```
   it "should assign_user_right" do
      .....
      assign_user_rights
      session[:index_all_users].should be_true
    end
```

The error:

```
Failure/Error: assign_user_rights
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `assign_user_rights' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4:0x57550e0>
```

Since assign_user_rights is defined in application controller, it should be readily visible in its spec file. However it is not the case as we see. What could be the problem with the code? Thanks.

Comment: Did you run `rails generate rspec:install`. And as a result of that, do you have an `spec/spec_helper.rb` file with content similar to this file: https://gist.github.com/1054053 ? If yes, make sure the method name is correct in both places.

Comment: "Since assign_user_rights is defined in application controller, it should be readily visible in its spec file."  Actually, no. The context an example runs in is entirely different from the context of a controller. `self` is not the same in these two contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `controller.assign_user_rights` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
get :assign_user_rights
response.should be_true
```

Comment: There is no route error. Using get needs to add route in routes.rb in controller, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the controller applications_controller_spec.rb is a sub class of application_controller.rb .

```
           If it's not a sub class of application controller,  call the method using controller_name.assign_user_rights
```